# node json in android studio

Tags: android, node.js

i am new in android. i write request code in nodejs that get database table. i try that with postman and it was correct and return json. but in android studio, it return empty in android monitor. below is my android code. where is my problem????

```
public class ActGroups extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_groups);

        get_groups();
    }

    void get_groups() {

        String url = mylib.clsVars.get_url(1);
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                     Log.i("resp", response);


                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Log.i("err",error.getMessage());

                    }
                }
        ) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                Map<String, String> map = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                map.put("name", Base64.encodeToString("".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                return map;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ActGroups.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

this is post man json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "u_name": "u",
        "u_family": "uu"
    },


    {
         "id": 3,
         "u_name": "a",
         "u_family": "aa"
    },

    {
        "id": 6,
        "u_name": "b",
        "u_family": "bb"
    }
]
```

and below is logcat output:

```
06-02 10:24:45.426 7151-7151/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-02 10:24:45.427 7151-7151/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-02 10:24:45.745 7151-7151/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication-1/lib/x86
06-02 10:24:45.757 7151-7151/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-02 10:24:45.939 7151-7151/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-02 10:24:46.829 7151-7172/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-02 10:24:46.947 7151-7151/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
06-02 10:24:47.130 7151-7167/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-02 10:24:47.130 7151-7167/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-02 10:24:47.155 7151-7167/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9b9d9460: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
06-02 10:24:47.173 7151-7167/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b9d9460: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99c997d0)
06-02 10:24:47.221 7151-7167/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b9d9460: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99c997d0)
06-02 10:24:47.488 7151-7151/com.example.hosseinry.myapplication I/err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

what is solution?

Comment: its not able to connect see this line I/err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: do you internet permission

Comment: Yes added to manifest _@SuhaibRoomy

Comment: What's next?_  @SuhaibRoomy

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP you use for your URL,make sure you use the internet IP,looks a bit like 192.168..... and not 10.0.2.2 or 127.0.0.1

Comment: I was not tested _@Hilary Mwape

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your test was not tested _@Hilary Mwape

Comment: Ok,let me know when you do

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What ip are you using in your url?

Comment: Ohhhh ok,if you still get error must be something else,are you testing this on emulator or actual device?

Comment: I'm testing the emulator

Comment: My server is local, and because it does not detect localhost on Android, I use this system IP.

Comment: Ok,then i dont know what it is

Comment: Ok,and just in case make sure you handle CORS errors on node server,those wont show in postman but will show on any other device used,so you should allow access to all your methods(POST GET and all you use)

Comment: I'm new to Android. I just could not help you